# PDF inside a navigational app using UITableView and UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, pdf, uiwebview

My goal is to make a navigational Table View iOS app, with each cell representing a different PDF. All PDFs will be local.

I based my Table code off of a tutorial.

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *selectedRoute = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedRoute = selectedRoute;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
     [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

I based my UIWebView code off of [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18SNmZ4lWak).

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *endereco = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Clinton" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:endereco];
    NSURLRequest *urlEndereco = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlEndereco];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Selected Route";
}
```

I replaced the textbox from the Table tutorial with the UIWebView, but I'm just getting a blank view when I run it. What else do I have to add to allow my pdf to appear?

Comment: is your web view valid? if it is loaded from the nib why are you adding it to subview, or if you have declared it in the .h and not alloc/init'ed it. Throw a breakpoint in there and make sure everything is what you think it is.

Comment: Wow that kind of went over my head. I'm sorry if this is asking too much, but if I zip and upload my folder, could you please take a look at it for me?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=ZCVPYIC7 You can also contact me at vgt207@aol.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your DetailViewController doesn't have the code from viewDidLoad that you have written, it just says:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Display the selected route.
    lblText.text = selectedRoute;

    //Set the title of the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Selected Route";
}
```

I also fixed your outlets in detail view controller, view should point to the encapsulating view, not the webView made a new outlet called webView connected to the webView.
[image]
http://ObjectivelyBetter.com/tests/SeniorProject.zip

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help. I have one additional question, how would I assign it to open a PDF with the same name of the cell? I've done a ' NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@" ' before would that work in this instance?

Comment: you're welcome. That is cool that you get to study iphone programming in High School. good luck.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to direct webview to open the pdf that corresponds with the cell name, instead of the static @"clinton" pdf? I tried @"%@%@" but I know I'm missing something else.

Comment: NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedRoute ofType:@"pdf"]; then get the fileURL for that.

Comment: YES it worked! I really do appreciate the help. It has been very difficult trying to find help on my project. You've helped a great deal. Now onto implementing a search bar...